# Convert Celsius to Fahrenheit - How to display inside of input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm learning Javascript, and i'm trying to create a simple script that takes the users celsius and covert it to Fahrenheit inside of the Fahrenheit input field. I'm able to console log the results, but i can't figure out how to input the Fahrenheit inside of the input field. [Codepen Here](https://codepen.io/stinkytofu3311/pen/dREYVW?editors=1010)

```
//Capture input string from .inputbox into TestVar
function testResults (form) {
    var TestVar = form.inputbox.value,
        numString = parseFloat(TestVar),
        text = "";

  return numString * 1.8 + 32;

}
// Celsius * 1.8 + 32 = Fahrenheit
console.log(testResults);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using [HTMLInputElement.value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement)

```js
 // Find the button in the document
 let btn = document.querySelector('input[type=button]');
 // Add a click event listener to the button
 btn.addEventListener ('click', e => {
     // Find the fahrenheit input field
     let f = document.querySelector('#fahrenheit');
     // Find the celsisus input field
     let c = document.querySelector('#celsisus');
     // Make the calculation from the fahrenheit value.
     // Save it to the celsisus input field using `c.value`
     // where `c` is the reference to the celsisus input
     c.value = parseFloat(f.value) * 1.8 + 32;
 });
```

```html
<form name="myform" action="" method="GET">
   <p>Convert Celsius to Fahrenheit </p>
   <p><input type="text" name="inputbox" value="" id="fahrenheit" placeholder="Fahrenheit"></p>
   <p><input type="text" name="fahrenheit" id="celsisus" value="" placeholder="Celsius"></p>
   <p><input type="button" NAME="button" Value="Click" ></p>
</form>
```

Comment: This does not work for me. Could you show me a code Snippet? My goal is to have the amount in field 1 (Celsius) to be converted to field 2 (Fahrenheit) after the users clicks the button.

Comment: Okay give me a moment

Comment: You actually should use `document.getElementById('fahrenheit')`, and add a change event on the celsius field.

Comment: @StinkyTofu I have added an example

Comment: You're throwing ES6 "stuff" at someone who is just beginning to learn JavaScript. Your code is super-complicated for that user. Not to mention single-letter variables and that `document.querySelector`. And you're adding a click handler when you can add a submit handler to the form.

Comment: I replaced C and F with Fahrenheit, and Celsius to help my noobie brain. What does e=> do? I've never seen that before.

What does celsius.value = parseFloat(fahrenheit.value) * 1.8 + 32; do?

Set the value of Celsius to value of Fahrenheit * 1.8 + 32?

Comment: It is shorthand for `function(e)`. The other part is doing what you did but in one line

Comment: I forked your fiddle and rearranged things (your formula was off, when I entered 100 in the F field it gave me 212 in the C field) and switched to a submit handler like @IsmaelMiguel suggested (I agree) https://jsfiddle.net/mLo8usku/ but I think if you're just learning you may as well start with ES6